# regex join groups into another

Tags: regex

Good morning,

I have to feed a parsing tool that uses regular expressions. The tool is written in java.
It can be fed simply like this:

expression(.*)

Means: Look for the expression and save the contents of group 1 (or 2 etc.) into a database column.

Now I have to parse receipts, where some of them have the wanted contents at expression1, and others at expression2.

So I seek like this:
expression1(.*)|expression2(.*)

So both expressions are found.

The problem is, that the tool can only save one groupX, not group1 or group2 if one is not null.

Is there a possibility, to wrap something arround the expression, so that the result appears allways in groupX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an alternation with a single capture group, e.g.

```
(?:expression1|expression2)(.*)
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks a lot!